# Including properties file outside of WAR but inside classpath

Tags: java, weblogic

So i have a web service which will be deployed as a war file (In Oracle Weblogic 12c), and they would like a properties.file outside of the war file (but in the classpath and not hardcoded path - which is what I have now)

All it will contain is

```
username=username
password=password
```

How would I go about setting/getting the file from the classpath? (And more importantly, where would this classpath be?)

Comment: are u by any chance using spring? If you are its easy to do so using the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer

Comment: No :( - It's not a very big app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is available from your classpath, then you can use either:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("fileName");
```

Or

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("fileName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add it to managed node class path?

```
<domain> -> Environment -> Servers -> Configuration -> Server start: Class Path
```

Add full path to the file location and restart managed node.